# Which head is marked as tip?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

The [documentation](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html) says:

> The tip tag is a special “floating” tag, which always identifies the
>   newest revision in the repository.

What is meant by the "newest"? Is it the one with the highest UTC time? Or the one most recently added to the local repository (i.e., the one with the highest local revision number)?

It seems from my experimentation that it's the latter. If it's true, what's the rationale of this choice?

Version 1.9.3 if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highest local revision number, yes

Because it's (logically) *most recent* changeset

Comment: BTW, it appears that the tip is not always what `hg update` (without arguments) updates to. It seems it would update to *the most recent head that is active* - if there is one (if there's none, it would update to the most recent head, whether active or not, i.e., the tip).

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use MQ, a `qrefresh` causes the refreshed changeset to be removed and re-added, so it automatically becomes tip.

Answer (score 0):

tip is the highest local revision which could be on a branch. hg update will update to the tip of the current named branch.  So if default or a named branch has the absolute tip of the repository but you are not set to use that branch you will get the latest on what you are set to use.  hg summary tells you what your current branch is.

Comment: To clarify my comment, I only have one named branch. It is multiple anonymous branches I'm talking about.